# How to make simple health check page for a reactJS app?

Tags: reactjs, json, http-headers, health-check

I'd like to make a simple healthcheck url for my reactJs application. So simple that I'd just like to make a page that returns status OK, which is hardcoded, since the goal is to just load a simple page with no other styles or scripts to load the page as fast as possible. So far I have achieved that, but what intrigues me is that healthcheck page should return a json output, like {healthcheck: ok} or {status:200}, and if I check the headers content type it should be application/json. Can anyone please give me idea to achieve that in reactJS?

This is how I simply display a status message. If this simple page loads then of course the server is working right?

```
const HealthCheck = () => {
  return (
    <>
      status: 200
      <br />
      environment: {process.env.NODE_ENV}
    </>
  )
}

export default HealthCheck
```

Then I have another way like this, to attempt to change the content-type in the headers to content type application/json instead of text/html. But it did not work, it's still text/html.

```
const HealthCheck = () => {

  var response = {}
  response['status'] = 200
  response['environment'] = process.env.NODE_ENV

  return JSON.stringify(response)
}

export default HealthCheck
```

Making this page returns status 200 and as application/json in the content type in the network tab is what I need to achieve. A the same time also display the json string in the healthcheck page itself.

Comment: You should show research, people want to see what you have research and what you have tried

Comment: How are you running this React component? Is it client side, server side, or prerendered?

Comment: @NickMcCurdy client side, as usual react front end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve this using React DOM on the client alone, because this renderer requires an HTML DOM, which only works if your client is responding with an HTML MIME type.

The solution would be to have a server with an API endpoint that responds with JSON, which you could then use with or without React. Here are some examples of approaches using different servers:

## Node

```js
import http from "http"

http
  .createServer((req, res) =>
    res
      .writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" })
      .end(JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)),
  )
  .listen()
```

## Remix and Node

```js
import { json } from "@remix-run/node"

export function loader() {
  return json(process.env.NODE_ENV, 200)
}
```

## Next

```js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json(process.env.NODE_ENV)
}
```

Comment: How would I display the response as raw json in the react front end? Assuming I used Node in backend

Comment: Make a `fetch` request in `useEffect`, set the response body to state, and render it with `JSON.stringify`.